# separating result data into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, components

I have one react component in which I have one `form` and `result table`. They both are in same file. I want to separate them into 2 different `component`. means result table into another component.
I have as of now `ListCertificate` component in which I have result is response array ,so I created  component to display the data.

in `ListCertificate` I wrote `<ResultTable response={response}>`

and in `ResultTable` I did `const ResultTable = (response)=>{ response.map() ... }` . but it is not rendering the table.

code snippet of first component from where data is getting passed.

```
        const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
                params: param,
            });
            console.log(data);
            setResponse(data);
<ResultTable response= {response} />    //This line
        };
```

Below is complete code of `ListCertificate` file, both `form` and `result table` code are present in this file. could you please guide me on the same.

```
    import React, { SyntheticEvent, useState } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Certificate from './models/certificate';
    
    const ListCertificate = () => {
        const [certificateNo, setCertificateNo] = useState('');
        const [protoColNo, setProtoColNo] = useState('');
        const [requestStatus, setRequestStatus] = useState('');
        const [researchTitle, setResearchTitle] = useState('');
        const [sponser, setSponser] = useState('');
        const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
        const [noOfSubjects, setNoOfSubjects] = useState('');
        const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
        const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');
        const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
        const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
    
        const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const param = {
                ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
                ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
                ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
                ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
                ...(country && { country: country }),
                ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
                ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
                ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
            };
            console.log(param);
            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
                params: param,
            });
            console.log(data);
            setResponse(data);
<ResultTable response= {response} />
        };
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={submit}>
                    <div className="row mb-12">
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Certificate No</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="certificateNo"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter the Certificate No"
                                onChange={(e) => setCertificateNo(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Protocol No</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                name="protoColNo"
                                placeholder="Enter the Protocol No"
                                onChange={(e) => setProtoColNo(e.target.value)}
                            ></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Status</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                name="requestStatus"
                                placeholder="Enter the Request Status"
                                onChange={(e) => setRequestStatus(e.target.value)}
                            ></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="row mb-12">
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Sponser</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                name="sponser"
                                placeholder="Enter the Sponser"
                                onChange={(e) => setSponser(e.target.value)}
                            ></input>
                        </div>
    
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Country</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control "
                                name="country"
                                placeholder="Enter the Country Name"
                                onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
                            ></input>
                        </div>
    
                        {/* <div className="col">
                            <label>Research Title</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter the Research Title"
                                onChange={(e) => setResearchTitle(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div> */}
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="row mb-12">
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>No Of Subjects</label>
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                name="noOfSubjects"
                                type="number"
                                placeholder="Enter the number of subjects"
                                onChange={(e) => setNoOfSubjects(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Start Date</label>
                            <input
                                type="date"
                                name="startDate"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter the Start Date"
                                onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
    
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>End Date</label>
                            <input
                                type="date"
                                name="endDate"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter the End Date"
                                onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-primary" onClick={submit}>
                                Submit Search
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
     <!---------------Result table code------------>
                        <div className="table-responsive">
                            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                                <thead className="bg-success">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Certificate No</th>
                                        <th>Sponser</th>
                                        <th>Protocol No</th>
                                        <th>Start Date</th>
                                        <th>End Date</th>
                                        <th># of Subjects</th>
                                        <th>Country</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {response.map((certificate: Certificate) => {
                                        return (
                                         <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
                                          <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.country}</td>
                                          <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
                                          <td>
                                             <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                                                <Link
                                                    to={`/certificates/${certificate.certificateNo}/edit`}
                                                    className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                                    <i className="bi bi-pencil"></i>
                                                </Link>
                                                
                                                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" >
                                                    <i className="bi bi-plus-square"></i>
                                                </button>
                                                
                                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"> - </a>
                                                
                                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" >
                                                    <i className="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
                                                </a>
                                                
                                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                                    <i className="bi bi-search"></i>
                                                </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    <td></td>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default ListCertificate;
```

I created 2 separate component.

ListCertificate:-

```
const ListCertificate = () => {
    const [certificateNo, setCertificateNo] = useState('');
    const [protoColNo, setProtoColNo] = useState('');
    const [requestStatus, setRequestStatus] = useState('');
    const [researchTitle, setResearchTitle] = useState('');
    const [sponser, setSponser] = useState('');
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
    const [noOfSubjects, setNoOfSubjects] = useState('');
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

    const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const param = {
            ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
            ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
            ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
            ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
            ...(country && { country: country }),
            ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
            ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
            ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
        };
        console.log(param);
        const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
            params: param,
        });
        console.log(data);
        setResponse(data);
    };


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <div className="row mb-12">
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Certificate No</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="certificateNo"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter the Certificate No"
                            onChange={(e) => setCertificateNo(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Protocol No</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name="protoColNo"
                            placeholder="Enter the Protocol No"
                            onChange={(e) => setProtoColNo(e.target.value)}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name="requestStatus"
                            placeholder="Enter the Request Status"
                            onChange={(e) => setRequestStatus(e.target.value)}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row mb-12">
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Sponser</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name="sponser"
                            placeholder="Enter the Sponser"
                            onChange={(e) => setSponser(e.target.value)}
                        ></input>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control "
                            name="country"
                            placeholder="Enter the Country Name"
                            onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
                        ></input>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Research Title</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter the Research Title"
                            onChange={(e) => setResearchTitle(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div className="row mb-12">
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>No Of Subjects</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            name="noOfSubjects"
                            type="number"
                            placeholder="Enter the number of subjects"
                            onChange={(e) => setNoOfSubjects(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <label>Start Date</label>
                        <input
                            type="date"
                            name="startDate"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter the Start Date"
                            onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <label>End Date</label>
                        <input
                            type="date"
                            name="endDate"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter the End Date"
                            onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-primary" onClick={submit}>
                            Submit Search
                        </button>
                    </div> 
                </div>        
            </form>  
           </div> 
        </div>
    );
};

export default ListCertificate;
```

ResultTable.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Certificate from './models/certificate';

const ResultTable = (response:any) => {
    return (
        
                   
        <div>
        <div className="table-responsive">
            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                <thead className="bg-success">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Certificate No</th>
                        <th>Sponser</th>
                        <th>Protocol No</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th># of Subjects</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {response.map((certificate: Certificate) => {
                        return (
                         <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
                          <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.country}</td>
                          <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
                          <td>
                             <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                                <Link
                                    to={`/certificates/${certificate.certificateNo}/edit`}
                                    className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                    <i className="bi bi-pencil"></i>
                                </Link>
                                
                                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" >
                                    <i className="bi bi-plus-square"></i>
                                </button>
                                
                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"> - </a>
                                
                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                    <i className="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
                                </a>
                                
                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                    <i className="bi bi-search"></i>
                                </a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                    <td></td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>   
        </div>
    )
}
export default ResultTable
```

Comment: *"but it was giving error"* ... what is the specific error? Always include error details in questions

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for responding. I put code of both the files also attached the error on page. there is no compilation error though.

Comment: That error would suggest that the `response` variable does not contain an array at the time the error occurs

Comment: But it is printing proper data if I have all the code in same file. am I doing any mistake while separating the code?

Comment: Do some debugging of what it is at the time you call that `map()` and the error occurs

Comment: thanks @charlietfl . I recorrected that but now seond component is not rendering the reesult. but there is no error. control is not reaching to second one.  <ResultTable response= {response} />

Comment: I put the snippet on top, how I am sending data to another component. is there any issue  on the same? in another component I am just reading the output. control is not reaching there.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by `control`.  Can you put a demo together in a codesandbox that reproduces problem?